# LDAP: error code 50 - no write access to parent while adding user in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to create a user in OpenLDAP through my Java code(which works in all of LDAP environments I have tried so far). When I tried it with OpenLDAP, I got the following error:

```
LDAP: error code 50 - no write access to parent
```

I am trying to create user in the testldap subdomain. My LDIF file controlling ACL is as follows:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess

olcAccess: {0}to dn.subtree="dc=testldap,dc=mydomain,dc=com" by self write by dn="cn=Manager,ou=People,dc=testldap,dc=mydomain,dc=com" write by dn="cn=Manager,ou=People,dc=testldap,dc=mydomain,dc=com" write by dn="cn=Manager,ou=People,dc=testldap,dc=mydomain,dc=com" read by dn="cn=Manager,ou=People,dc=testldap,dc=mydomain,dc=com" search by anonymous auth

olcAccess: {1}to  * by self write by dn="cn=admin,cn=config" write by dn.children="ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=com" read by dn.children="ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=com" search by anonymous auth
```

What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an interesting issue. I removed the line breaks and it worked like a charm. :)